# How to use stageVideo for Air iOS (Flash Professional CS5.5)?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am creating a very basic App for the iPhone & iPad and it's being built in Flash Professional CS5.5. All the actionscript is done on the frames (inline?) as I'm not familiar with using classes and external .as files etc. I've been meaning to learn that method but just haven't gotten around to it.

So my question is, what is the simplest way to use stageVideo to play a video attached to the IPA? I have looked at various sites such as http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html and spent hours on Google looking for examples, but all the examples and source files are either: external classes, flex, or flash builder. I can't find a simple .fla example where all the code is internally placed.

Comment: You need to learn how to use external files, for code management alone.  Also, most examples you will find dealing with this type of functionality expect you to know and use it, because there are usually many methods (functions) to handle the various events and errors that can occur.  Sorry for the non-answer, but I think most of the examples are pretty clear.  Also read the [StageVideo docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the wmode=direct in the Name-app.xml. If you find a way to edit it, tell me please, cause I don't know how to do it on Flash Professional =/